# ASP.NET Core Web App with Azure AD reply url specified in the request does not match the reply urls configured

Tags: asp.net-core-2.1, azure-authentication

I am trying to work with ASP.NET Core 2.1 and securing a Web App with Azure AD. I have my appsettings as follows:

```
{
  "AzureAd": {
    "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
    "Domain": "xxxx.onmicrosoft.com",
    "ClientId": "xxxxx",
    "TenantId": "xxxxx",
    "ClientSecret": "xxxxx",
    "CallbackPath": "/signin-oidc"
  },
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}
```

(Note the callbackPath). This is as per the documentation I could locate. When I last worked with Azure AD auth, I used a reply url in the app settings, and this had to match the reply URL in Azure AD. However the documentation for this newer method says you must have the call back path as /signin-oidc ?

I don't really understand, but I've set it that way, however I can't set the reply url in Azure AD Application Registration to this, as it doesn't accept this 'partial' path. It has to be a full URL. I've tried:

- mysite.net (with callbackPath as mysite.net)
- mysite.net/index (with CallbackPath as /index)
- mysite.net/signin-oidc (with CallbackPath as /signin-oidc"

But I continually get the error url specified in the request does not match the reply urls configured for sign in after putting in my credentials when the challenge occurs and I get the microsoft login page.

When I last did Azure AD Auth with ASP.NET webforms, it was just the app.config having mysite.net as the reply url, and application registration in Azure as mysite.net

Comment: It should be mysite.net/signin-oidc (with CallbackPath as /signin-oidc". You can find the correct reply url in your request url.

Comment: Refer to this sample https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/resources/samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-openidconnect-aspnetcore/

Comment: the correct redirect_uri will exist in your request when login https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/authorize?client_id=&response_type=code&redirect_uri=https://localhost:8080&response_mode=query&resource=

Comment: I have now set Azure AD reply Url to https://example.net/signin-oidc and the CallBackPath to /signin-oidc and it appears now the sign in works but i get a 404 as the page https://example.net/signin-oidc does not exist. Am I missing something here? Do I actually need to create a signin-oidc.html page as some kind of mandatory page in my asp.net core 2.1 solution? Probably not, so I'm clearly not understanding something else :)

Comment: How did you secure your Web App with Azure AD?

Comment: By registering the web app as an application in Azure Active Directory / Application Registration, and setting Implicit Grant = ID Tokens, Treat as Public Client = No, and Accounts in this organizational directory only = Yes.  Have also set a reply Url as mentioned in my previous comment. I have also updated my appSettings.json with the appropriate tenant, client secret as generated in app registration etc.

Answer (score 2):

Solution in 2 parts:

Part 1: Ensure CallBackUrl in the appsettings.json is /signin-oidc and in azure app registration is yoursite/signin-oidc

Part 2: Ensure you add app.UseAuthentication() to your HTTP pipeline in startup.cs